# Join count as a column in the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Business and BusinessCat. I need a MSSQL Query that will get me the following result:

```
ID | CategoryName | RecordCount
1  | Local        | 3
2  | National     | 1
3  | International| 2
4  | Other        | 0
```

I need the count of how many there are in each category as another column.

Business table looks like this:

```
ID | Category | BusinessName
1  | 3        | Blackstone, Inc.
2  | 2        | Pet Smart
3  | 1        | John Doe
4  | 3        | Best Buy
5  | 1        | Sams Treats
6  | 1        | Eastcoast Tattoo
```

BusinessCat table looks like this:

```
ID | CategoryName
1  | Local
2  | National
3  | International
4  | Other
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CN.ID, CN.CategoryName, ISNULL(Count(B.ID), 0) AS RecordCount
FROM Business B
RIGHT JOIN BusinessCat CN
ON B.Category = CN.ID
GROUP BY CN.ID, CN.CategoryName
```

or

```
SELECT CN.ID, CN.CategoryName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Business B WHERE B.Category = CN.ID) AS RecordCount
FROM BusinessCat CN
```

Check which query is faster.

Comment: The first one won't return the row for which there are 0 entries in business table, the second will, though :) got it wrong in my solution too..

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej: Why wouldn't it return anything? There's a LEFT JOIN. Your solution is, effectively, using an INNER JOIN. He has a ISNULL check around Business.ID. It should totally work.

Comment: @Ellesedil no, it will not help - see here what I'm talking about: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8196/5

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej: Ah, the tables are in the wrong order. Or, it should be a RIGHT JOIN. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8196/8

Comment: Right, RIGHT join :) didn't see that, thought there was another problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, got it wrong, should be (like other people stated):

```
SELECT bc.id, bc.categoryname, COUNT(b.id)
  FROM businesscat bc LEFT JOIN business b ON (bc.id = b.category)
GROUP BY bc.id, bc.categoryname
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `Group By` + `Count`:

```
SELECT bc.ID, bc.CategoryName, RecordCount = COUNT(b.ID)
FROM BusinessCat bc LEFT OUTER JOIN Business b
    ON bc.ID = b.Category
GROUP BY bc.ID, bc.CategoryName
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4baa/10/0)</kbd>

Comment: It's actually wrong (as is mine) - your query returns 1 for category 4, where it should return 0, bacause there are no rows in business table related to that category.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej: Whoops, you're right, thanks. Changed it from `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(b.ID)`.

Comment: @tim how had you make that button ??

Comment: @Dhaval: Use `<kbd>[link-text](url)</kbd>`. The `kbd` is a shortcut for keyboard which looks like a button.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
select bc.id, bc.cat_name, count(b.cat)
 from Business b (nolock)
inner join businesscat bc (nolock)
on b.cat=bc.id
group by bc.id, bc.cat_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Left/Right Join as:

```
SELECT CN.ID, CN.CategoryName, isnull(Count(B.ID),0) RecCount
FROM Business B
RIGHT JOIN BusinessCat CN
              ON B.Category = CN.ID
GROUP BY CN.ID, CN.CategoryName
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select
      BC.ID,
      BC.CategoryName,
      coalesce( count(B.ID), 0 ) as RecordCount
   from
      BusinessCat BC
         LEFT JOIN Business B
            on BC.ID = B.Category
   group by
      BC.ID,
      BC.CategoryName
   ORDER BY
      BC.ID
```

You need a LEFT-JOIN to the business categories table to allow that one entry of no records to remain showing in the final list.

Comment: I don't understand why this has negative votes. Is `COALESCE` scaring people?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, it kept asking me to use Group By rather than Order By.

Comment: @kcray: Ha, didn't even notice that.

Comment: @Ellesedil, sorry, I was away and missed the group by.  As for why others so blatently down-voted the context of the answer just because I brain-cramped the group by, well, I have other opinions of them.  This one WILL get what you are looking for